# preg_match_all with multiple occurance

Tags: php, regex

I have a set a string and I have a set of array words. I need a function those return the words matches from the array with string.

Here is an example of string and array

```php
$string = "Name the structures undercover of flexor retinaculum of the foot.";

$matchList = array( "Hyperactivity","flexor","Adjustment","retinaculum","name", "flexor retinaculum" );
```

I tried with `preg_match_all`. But in the result, it doesn't get all the words matches.

Eg: `flexor retinaculum`.

Here is the method that I used.

```php
$matchList = array_map( function( $value ) {
            return preg_quote( $value, '/' );
        }, $matchList );

$matchList = implode( '|', $matchList );

// Set the regex.
$regex = '/\b(?:)(' . $matchList . ')(\b)/i';

preg_match_all( $regex, $string, $result );
```

Comment: What is `(?:)` supposed to be doing?

Comment: What is `strip_tags( $text_array )`? What does not work? If you want to use `$string` instead https://3v4l.org/kohoY I think the code should be like this `$regex = '/\b(?:' . $matchList . ')\b/i';`

Comment: Maybe `$text_array` should be `$string`???

Comment: Yes exactly. It's actually a mistake and I changed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Got the solution**!!!!!!!!!

I created a custom function with `recursion` which removes the matched keywords from the array.

Here I used `array_chunk` to handle if the `wordList` array have more than `500` length. In my scenario, there are more than 500 words in the array.

```
function findMatchList( $textString, $wordList )
    {
        $wordList = array_chunk($wordList,500);
        $matchListFinal = [];
        foreach($wordList as $wordSub)
        {
            $wordListString = implode( '|', $wordSub );

            // Set the regex.
            $regex = '/\b(?:)(' . $wordListString . ')(\b)/i';

            preg_match_all( $regex, $textString, $matchList );
            if( isset( $matchList[0] ) && count( $matchList[0] ) ) {

                $wordSub = array_udiff( $wordSub, $matchList[0], 'strcasecmp' );

                $matchList = array_merge( $matchList[0], $this->_findMatchList( $textString, $wordSub ) );
            }
            else
                $matchList = [];

            $matchListFinal = array_merge($matchListFinal,$matchList);

        }

        return $matchListFinal;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`flexor retinaculum` is not matched because `flexor` and `retinaculum` have a higher precedence in your regex boolean.

Ignoring the issue with `(?:)` your regex is:

```
/\b(?:)(Hyperactivity|flexor|Adjustment|retinaculum|name|flexor retinaculum)(\b)/i
```

`flexor retinaculum` as a single term is never found because `flexor` and `retinaculum` were found first and regex does not recurse to the beginning once it has a match.

If you wanted to do this recursively then you need to loop each `$matchList` item and perform a fresh regex against `$string`.

---

If you change your regex to:

```
/\b(?:)(Hyperactivity|flexor retinaculum|flexor|Adjustment|retinaculum|name)(\b)/i
```

Then `flexor retinaculum` will be matched as a whole but not individually.

Answer (score 0):

Shorter matches appear first, so sorting by the length so that longer matches are captured first may work.  This will match `flexor retinaculum`, but if it matches, it won't then match `flexor` and  `retinaculum` individually.  If `flexor retinaculum` is not matched, it will then match `flexor` and  `retinaculum`:

```
usort($matchList, function($a, $b){
    return (strlen($b) - strlen($a));
});

$matchList = implode('|', $matchList);
```

Then use a simpler regex:

```
$regex = '/\b(' . $matchList . ')\b/i';
```

And of course your string is `$string` so use that:

```
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $result);
```

Comment: But I need to match all the keywords in the array including `flexor`, `retinaculum` & `flexor retinaculum`